# Encryption using public key

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ios5

My code:

```
SecKeyRef oPublicKey = [self getPublicKeyRef];
SecKeyRef oPrivateKey = [self getPrivateKeyRef];

CFDictionaryRef myDictionary;

CFTypeRef keys[2];
CFTypeRef values[2];

// Initialize dictionary of key params
keys[0] = kSecAttrKeyType;
values[0] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA;
keys[1] = kSecAttrKeySizeInBits;
int iByteSize = 1024;
values[1] = CFNumberCreate( NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &iByteSize );
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate( NULL, keys, values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), NULL, NULL );

// Generate keys
OSStatus status = SecKeyGeneratePair( myDictionary, &oPublicKey, &oPrivateKey );
if ( status != 0 )
    NSLog( @"SecKeyGeneratePair failed" );

// Encrypt some data
uint8_t* pPlainText = (uint8_t*)"6921";

uint8_t aCipherText[1024];
size_t iCipherLength = 1024;
status = SecKeyEncrypt( oPublicKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1, pPlainText, strlen( (char*)pPlainText ) + 1, &aCipherText[0], &iCipherLength );

if ( status != 0 )
    NSLog( @"SecKeyEncrypt failed" );

NSMutableData *data12=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data12 appendBytes:aCipherText length:strlen( (char*)aCipherText ) + 1];
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data12 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Encrypted Text:::%@",string1);

// Decrypt the data
uint8_t aPlainText[1024];
size_t iPlainLength = 1024;
status = SecKeyDecrypt( oPrivateKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1, &aCipherText[0], iCipherLength, &aPlainText[0], &iPlainLength );
if ( status != 0 )
    NSLog( @"SecKeyDecrypt failed" );

NSLog(@"FINAL decrypted text: %s", aPlainText);
```

I am using this code for encryption but we are getting output like:

> N$)  : )¥=wÞ¢#4+ ’MO, œÝÕ‘*#2< xÕ™‘Hþ   a Â f¦*šU;f£Æì ø¤VØ´ÿ ÷ påcx ¨¢¯Ô)Õ#k Ë«: çÑ5
>   õ°7\Û‰z~“9GX>M¼êeë¿†w¥ro¬ ›gP4s2µ)9; p

But how to get NSString format ?Is there any wrong step in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Always [pad your plain text](http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/06/why-rsa-encryption-padding-is-critical/). [PKCS #1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) is the standard padding for RSA encryption.

Also, be aware that with RSA public key encryption, you can only encrypt/decrypt data up to the size of the key (minus a few overhead bytes).

Public key encryption is typically used only to encrypt a key (and hash), which is then used for symmetric encryption (and verification) of the actual payload.